# Ubuntu 18.10: How do I get the old icons back

Tags: 18.04, themes, icon-themes, 18.10

Ubuntu 18.10 added in new icons and a new GTK theme. However I prefer the old icons and GTK theme. Is it possible to get the icons and ambience theme from Ubuntu 18.04 into 18.10?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt install light-themes`

to install the old theme and icons. Also install the GNOME Tweak Tool if you haven't installed it yet. Open the GNOME Tweak Tool, and go to the "Appearance" tab. Set "Applications" to "Ambiance", set "Cursors" to "DMZ-White", and set "Icons" to "Ubuntu-mono-light"

Comment: I took the freedom to remove ubuntu-mono from your command. It is also a dependency of light-themes, and will therefore automatically be installed along wiht light-themes.